# SharedPreferences not returning all entries

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**My Code:**

```
protected SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", 0);
Map<String, ?> allPrefs = prefs.getAll();
```

Executing above returns only the first preference.

The preferences page looks okay, and selected values get saved well.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: "The preferences page displays ok" You mean a PreferenceFragment?

Comment: did you check all keys and values of allPrefs like this for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Log.d("map", entry.getKey() + ": " + 
                                   entry.getValue().toString());            
 }

Comment: I checked the value 'allPrefs' by hovering over it, and expanding the debug pane.